# Hibernate attempts to delete parent entity in unidirectional ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple unidirectional ManyToOne relationship on an entity, which unfortunately is defined in a schema I cannot change.

It is defined as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Profile")
...
public class Profile{
  
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="usr_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
  private User usr;
...
```

and all is well. The relationship is enforced with a foreign key in the db, hence the nullable = false and updatable = false. There is no mention of the profiles in user.
When I try to delete a Profile, hibernate also tries to delete the User entity, which is parent to other relationships and therefore fails. I have no CascadeType annotations anywhere.

My intent is to have a simple reference to the user using this profile in the usr field. This is a unidirectional relationship. The user entity should not be affected whenever I delete a profile.
This appers to be achievable when the usr field may be dereferenced before delete (I can see in the hibernate generated sql that hibernate attempts to set the field to null before deletion) - however that fails because of the foreign key.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable? If so, how?

(I'm using spring data on top of hibernate, if that is relevant.)

further Infos: I have tried optional=false, and it leads to the delete the parent entity behaviour. I have tried all fitting combinations of CascadeTypes, @OnDelete with NO_ACTION (still tries to delete the user) and defining a reverse but owned by user relationship - no success so far. On top of that, I tried the search function ;), which lead me to the conclusion that this is just my problem. If I missed an answered question, I'd appreciate a pointer in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some kind of other non-nullable association `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` to the `Profile` entity? You can debug into the deletion process by setting a break point in e.g. the JDBC driver in e.g. `Connection.prepareStatement` and go down the stack frames to the cascading part to figure out why this cascading happens.

If all that doesn't help, please create a reproducing [test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) and submit an issue to the [Hibernate issue tracker](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/).

Comment: I do have other @ManyToOne relationships in that type, though IIRC no non nullable ones. I'll check on monday, as I have no access to the code right now.
But just out of curiosity, why would that be significant? 
I tried debugging that part before, but between spring data and hibernate, I lost myself in layers of code - that hasn't happened in years, so I will try again on monday, just to see if I can still debug :)

If nothing helps, and since this is not my code, rather the code of a customer, I'll have to reproduce a test case the hopefully shows the same behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: Deleting an object that might be referred to through a non-null association might lead to the owner of the association to be deleted as well which could be the issue here.

Comment: So, I checked, and there are no other non nullabel relationships. I will try to reproduce a test case, as I have no more access to the code in question (as of today). Apart from having the actual problem (which I don't anymore), I really like to understand this behaviour, since I haven't had a problem with hibernate that I couldn't understand or tackle in years ;) Thank you very much for your answer.